# How to update a table based on some specific condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table, which is like below.
[image]

I want it to be updated to below.
[image]

Basically, per the records where `A_ID<>0 and B_ID<>0, C_ID=0`, if they have corresponding records which have the same `A_ID and B_ID`, while `C_ID<>0`(`A_ID=1001 and A_ID=1002` in this case), set `IsCurrent=0`, `ActiveTo` to corresponding `ActiveFrom - 1 second`.

Thanks

Comment: Which version of sql serveR?

Comment: @KannanKandasamy SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm . . . You can identify the records as:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(ActiveFrom) over (partition by a_id, b_id order by c_id) as next_ActiveFrom
      from t
     ) t
where c_id = 0 and next_ActiveFrom is not null;
```

Then update them:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*
      from (select t.*,
                   lead(ActiveFrom) over (partition by a_id, b_id order by c_id) as next_ActiveFrom
            from t
           ) t
      where c_id = 0 and next_ActiveFrom is not null
     )
update toupdate
    set isactive = 0,
        activeTo = dateadd(second, -1, next_ActiveFrom);
```

Comment: That is quick. Thanks.